# Creating Windows 8 Metro app (HTML5) without Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I know this might be a stupid question but is there any way to build a Windows 8 Metro app (HTML5) without using Visual Studio? As I have understod it, an html5 metro app consists out of typical web files (html/js/css/images) and a manifest file. Is it possible to simply zip a directory with the required files and use that as an application? Or am I way off?

Best regards Vic

Comment: Nothing is stopping your from writing your code in notepad. You may be able to compile with msbuild, which would require the Windows SDK (formerly .NET Framework SDK) instead of VS.

Comment: Can you explain why you would do this? Visual Studion 11 Express which can create these metro style javascript apps will be available free!

Comment: That's always good to know. First of all, I preffer to develop on Mac, not Windows. Second of all, I preffer to work in an IDE of my choise, which really isn't visual studio. But I will of course give it a try..

Comment: + every time you try to give visual studio a go, it installs 30gbs of packages..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Information on the PowerShell scripts you can use to package and deploy an app, then run it from the Start screen, can be found on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/5013262a-2a18-4ce6-99d1-03451d6c9619. The problem is that this won't get you very far with debugging, which is one of the greatest values of a tool like VS. (And don't forget Blend...an excellent tool for styling and debugging CSS).

I've heard that people do get scared off by VS (myself included), but the Express edition for Win8 is straightforward to use, and the IntelliSense you get for JS, WinJS, and WinRT is exceptionally helpful. And did I mention debugging?

Honestly, when we were first able to write Metro style apps at all in Dec 2010, we only had the PowerShell scripts to do all of this, and did, in fact, write code in Notepad. It was utterly painful...had to debug HTML and script in a browser with F12 tools, but then you couldn't use WinRT APIs. Gradually VS got better and better and it's simply worth spending some time learning in lieu of other IDEs becoming available for the Win8 platform.

Comment: I wanted to add that in my now-released book, Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (a free ebook from Microsoft Press, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx), I made a video that introduces Visual Studio basics in about 10 minutes. Download the companion content and look in the Chapter 2 folder for Video 2-1.

Comment: It's all great, but it still requires at least 1G RAM (in reality probably 2G or more) and 8 GB drive space. While the Jetbrains IDE I am currently running requires 350MB memory and 450 MB drive space, so I am able to run it even on a cheap tablet.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. There's a very good tutorial [here](http://peterdn.com/post/To-make-a-Metro-Appx-Package-from-scratch-you-must-first-e280a6.aspx). It uses C# rather than HTML5/JavaScript, but for the most part it is the same. It was written for the CTP release of Windows 8 though, so a few things have changed with the Release Preview, but it should be a good starting point.